# How to handle class's from Two Different .Java Files?

Tags: java, android, function, class, call

I have two java class file's in my project.

First one is main.Java
Second one is function.java

How to call function.java method from main.java

for Example.

main.Java

```
public class main {

//call function here
}
```

function.Java

```
public class function {    

public void example(){

   System.out.println("Function working");
}

}
```

How to call function.java example method from Main.Java?

Comment: so you have two `public class function {}` which you save as main.java and function.java? I don't think that's how Java works..

Comment: First your code will not compile. You cannot have public class name and java file name different.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class name should be always start with Upper letter.

This is the way to call a function in another class in another .java
In Main.java

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SecondClass sc = new SecondClass();
        sc.go();
    }
}
```

In SecondClass.java

```
public class SecondClass{
    public void go(){
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

If you want to call the method in the same class

```
    public class Main{
        public void go(){
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Main m = new Main();
            m.go();
        }
    }
```

or this

```
public class Main{
    public static void go(){
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        go();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make the example() method static

```
public static void example(){
System.out.println("Function working");
}
```

Then call

```
public class main {

//call function here
public static void main(String[] args) {
    function.example();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if they are not in the same package you should import function.java in main.java like this

```
import function
```

then you should create an instance of function class like this where you want to use it

```
function func = new function();
```

then you can call the example method using func object you created like this

```
func.example();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method isn't static, so you need to instantiate object from this class(function) to obtain access to the example method. First of all read some java specific book, so you can understand what static keyword is and how you can use it.

Answer (score -1):

The code below will work :

```
package main.Java; //this is from where you want to call.

public class function {
    public void inFunction(){
        function.Java.function function = new function.Java.function();
        function.example();
    }
}
```

Happy learning :)

Comment: @sabish Why this is accepted as answer? This is not what you asked for.

Comment: @Rajesh he wanted to call the function in different pkg... so this helps right?